# Unable to run git-commit-id-plugin once and use in child projects

Tags: git, pom.xml, maven-3

In the root of my project is pom.xml and .git.  My maven pom.xml looks like:

```
<profile>
      <id>git</id>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <exists>.git</exists>
        </file>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>revision</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>validate</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

From the console output, I can see that it is run once this way, but child jars that attempt to set it in the manifest end up having: '${git.commit.id.abbrev}' verbatim.

While I could just run this each time for each project, I'd like to run it once.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a profile is the wrong way. The plugin will handle all the cases required. Also setting `dotGitDirectory` is not necessary nor useful that is the default of the plugin. That violates the convention over configuration paradigm.

First define the version and the basic configuration of the plugin via `pluginManagement` like this:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
      <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <runOnlyOnce>true</runOnlyOnce>
        <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
        <commitIdGenerationMode>full</commitIdGenerationMode>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

some of the configurations parts might be changed if required `generateGitPropertiesFile` maybe?

The part `runOnlyOnce` is an important one within a multi module build which means the plugin itself will execute only once to read the Git information and only at the root level (where the `.git` directory can be found). If you don't set that to `true` it will try to read the Git information in each child which is not necessary (that works but it's a wast of time; only in case where you might use Git submodules/subtrees it might be required).

The next important thing is to bind the plugin to the life cycle. That has to be done in the `plugins` section (NOT in pluginManagement) like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ..
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The plugin itself binds by default to the `initialize` phase so it is not required to define the phase on your own.

Comment: Thanks, I think that did the trick.  I still haven't come across the plugin docs.  What benefit do I have of using plugin management?  It forces the version and configuration, but is the reasoning for that in a multi-module project is to prevent it from being overridden by a child module?  Is there additional benefit?

Comment: No it does not prevent overwriting in childs... but it centralizes the configuration and version at a particular location... and gives you a hint that you might create a corporate parent which contains that part later on and generalize that for a. lot of project...and also a clear separation of concern...